# Line thickness of links

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Links coming from `ref` or `gls` are accompanied by boxes (I know about `colorlinks` and the possibility to switch them off). I somehow like the idea of the boxes but the lines are way to thick in my opinion. Is there a way to make them thinner? I didn't find anything in hyperref, except `pdfborder` which seems to work for Sumatra but not Acrobat reader.

Just to clarify I mean the red box in this image:

[image]

Comment: Did you write `\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0.4}}` to have a 0.4pt linewidth? For me, it works  with Adobe Reader as well.

Comment: @Bernard. Hm this didn't work for me. I had to but the border at 0.6 and make the link color brighter as explained in the answer from `wipert`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This parameter is controlled by the attribute at PDF low level:

```
attr{/C[red green blue] /Border[0 0 thin]}
```

for example

```
attr{/C[1 0 0] /Border[0 0 .6]}
```

My experiences show that doing this lines thinner than .6 bp makes the lines invisible on some PDF viewers. Unfortunately. So, I advice to make the color less striking.

Comment: Ah, that's the thing. Thank you for pointing this out. In fact I tried something like `pdfborder = {0 0 0.6 [0.1 0.1]},` which even resulted in crashing Acrobat... It's a shame that this reader is still a standard reader...

Answer (score 6):

Option `pdfborder` is the way to go with `hyperref`. The "exact" definition of the three values can be found in the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) (units are bp):

- First value: horizontal corner radius,
- second value: vertical corner radius,
- the third value is the line thickness,
- as forth element, a dash array can be provided.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \autoref{eq:einstein}\quad
  {\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 2}\autoref{eq:einstein}}\quad
  {\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 .5}\autoref{eq:einstein}}

  \newpage
  \setcounter{chapter}{5}
  \setcounter{equation}{1}
  \begin{equation}
  E=mc^2\label{eq:einstein}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However, the interpretation heavily depends on the PDF viewer.
For example, the line thickness does not scale with the zoom level.

AR9/Linux, 100% and 200%:

> [image: AR9/Linux, 100%]
>   [image: AR9/Linux, 200%]

xpdf 3.03, 100% and 200%:

> [image: xpdf, 100%]
>   [image: xpdf, 200%]

The line thickness in AR remains constant regardless of zoom factor.
A different way of interpreting the line thickness is done by xpdf. There the thickness follows the zoom level.

**BTW, important note:**
Curly braces are needed around the value for `pdfborder`, if the option is given in `\usepackage`, because LaTeX would strip the spaces between the values otherwise. The curly braces are not necessary, when the values are set in `\hypersetup`.

```
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 1}]{hyperref}
```

Comment: I don't see any result on changing the first and/or second values to, say, 2. Ang I don't understand how to specify the fourth element to obtain a dashed frme (is that so?).

Comment: @Bernard If you don't see change in line thickness, then you need a PDF viewer, which supports these settings.

Comment: Oberdieck: You misunderstood me: I see the difference between `pdfborder={0 0 0.5}` and  `pdfborder={0 0 2}`. But what about, say  `pdfborder={2 0 0.5}`? I don't see any difference using 0 or 2 as first parameter. Btw, I use SumatraPDF, but also occasionally Adobe Reader or PDFXChange Viewer.

Comment: @Bernard Each viewer is different, there might be rounding issues, or a viewer is using a minimal width (1 pixel).

Comment: Oberdieck: maybe, but each of my three viewers give the same result. And wh

Comment: @Bernard Make screenshots at different zoom levels and border width values and ask the authors of the PDF viewers about it.